# lower_bound for vector of a struct applied for comparing strings

Tags: c++

I would like to ask you for a question, but firstly I will explain it...

I have a structure SPerson in the vector People.

```
typedef struct SPERSON {
   string name;
   string address;
   string birthcertificatenumber;
} SPerson;
std::vector<SPerson> People;
People.resize(100);
counter = 0;
```

There is a class where is the function for adding a new person

```
bool NewPerson(const string & name, const string & address, const string & birthcertifikatenumber)
{
   SPerson sPerson;
   sPerson.name = name;
   sPerson.address = address;
   sPerson.birthcertificatenumber = birthcertificatenumber;
   People[counter] = sPerson;
   counter++;
 return true;
}
```

In this function I need to check whether there is already a person WITH THE SAME NAME "AND" ADDRESS OR a person WITH THE BIRTH CERTIFICATE NUMBER

I need to search it logharitmicaly, not linearly.

I used the function inside the NewPerson that is below which works how I want but when having a lot of data, it is slow and I need to have quicker. I have heard about lower_bound function
for binary search, but I do not know how to apply it for my case. Can you please give me an advice. Thank you.

```
 auto it = find_if(begin(People), end(People), [=] (SPerson const& f) { 
    return (((strcasecmp(name.c_str(), f.name.c_str()) == 0) and (strcasecmp(address.c_str(), f.address.c_str()) == 0)) or (f.birthcertifikatenumber == birthcertifikatenumber));  
    });
bool found = (it != end(People)); 
if (found == true)
{    
    return false;
}
```

---

@Slava: Thank you, it actually works just fine.

I have these records on input:

- Name: John, address:eee, birth date certificate:abcdef
- Name: Pierre, address:aaa, birth date certificate:123456
- Name: Jean, address:bbb, birth date certificate:1234
- Name: Peter, address:ccc, birth date certificate:ABCDEF

It sorts by the birt date cerfificate just like this:

- Name: Jean, address:bbb, birth date certificate:1234
- Name: Pierre, address:aaa, birth date certificate:123456
- Name: Peter, address:ccc, birth date certificate:ABCDEF
- Name: John, address:eee, birth date certificate:abcdef

And by the name and address it sorts like this:

- Name: Jean, address:bbb, birth date certificate:1234
- Name: John, address:eee, birth date certificate:abcdef
- Name: Peter, address:ccc, birth date certificate:ABCDEF
- Name: Pierre, address:aaa, birth date certificate:123456

Great, thank you. Now I would like to find a person either by its name and address or by the birth date cerfificat, so I can call the functions like:
ErasePerson("Peter", "ccc");  // erasing the person by its name and address
ErasePerson("123456");  // erasing the person by its birth date cerfificate

I would like to use the O(log n), so now I would like to find the specific person and erase it. I am not sure how to use the lower_bound function. I have tried some things, but no success. I am not sure how to create the compare function and if that I have is correct.

```
 struct SPerson {
     string name;
     string address;
     string birthdatecertificate;
};   
std::vector<SPerson> VPeople;
std::vector<size_t> idxNameAddress;

bool People::ErasePerson(const string & name, const string & address)
{
   SPerson Person;
   Person.name = name;
   Person.address = address;
   Person.birthdatecertificate= ""; 

  std::lower_bound(idxNameAddress.begin(), idxNameAddress.end(), Person, cmpFunction);
return false;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior in the line `People[counter] = sPerson;`. You need to use `push_back` for adding new elements, since there is no guarantee that `People[counter]` will point to a valid memory (unless you used `resize` first).

Comment: Do not do `typedef struct` in C++, it is ugly and completely redundant.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius OP does show `resize()` in his code

Comment: @Slava Then, I guess I am blind. I guess, since the `resize` was hidden among the `struct`, and global(?) variable definitions, I didn't see the `resize` there. Now, I doubt that the snippet is even from the global scope. In addition, OP still has UB, if the number of elements exceed `100`, since he doesn't have any checks to enforce such a limit (and I neglected to mention that, since I didn't even see the `resize`).

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound` can only be used fr sorted containers (else, you'll get an invalid result...with no warning/error), which is not the case of your `std::vector`.

The easiest would be to store your elements in a sorted container. Like a `std::set` or `std::map`. Then your sorted container will be able to report if an object is already present with non-linear search algorithm.

Those container will require you to provide a comparison operator:

```
bool operator<(const SPERSON& left, const SPERSON& right )
{
    return left.name < right.name;
}
```

Then do:

```
std::set<SPERSON> People;
```

Add elements by using:

```
if ( People.find( sPerson ) == People.end() )
    People.insert( sPerson );
// else: item with same name already exists!
```

Comment: "already present with the fastest search algorithms" this statement is at least questionable if not wrong.

Comment: @Slava: Would "with non-linear search algorithm" be more accurate? `std::set` search is binary, isn't it?

Comment: The problem with `set`/`map` is that it can't have *two* keys simultaneously. The problem defines two keys, Name+Address and BirthCertificate.

Comment: Thank you for the anwer. Unfortunatelly I cannot use set, neither map. It is  in the introduction of the taks for the Software programming.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `typedef struct` is completely unnecessary in C++, just define your structure:

```
struct SPerson {
   string name;
   string address;
   string birthcertificatenumber;
};
std::vector<SPerson> People;
```

unlike C you can use `struct` name without keyword `struct` hence that idiom is redundant.

Now to be able to use `std::lower_bound` your data must be sorted. As you have 2 different criteria you would have to create index to speed up your lookup:

```
std::vector<SPerson> People;
std::vector<size_t> idxNameAddress;
std::vector<size_t> idxBirthCertificate;
```

and you need to keep indexes updated when you insert new person:

```
bool insertPerson( const SPerson &p ) {
    const auto cmpNameAddress = []( size_t u1, size_t u2 ) {
         const SPerson &p1 = People[u1];
         const SPerson &p2 = People[u2];
         return std::tie( p1.name, p1.address ) < std::tie( p2.name, p2.address );
    }
    const auto cmpBirthSert = []( size_t u1, size_t u2 ) {
         const SPerson &p1 = People[u1];
         const SPerson &p2 = People[u2];
         return p1.birthcertificate < p2.birthcertificate;
    }
}
    size_t newId = People.size();
    People.push_back( p );
    auto p1 = std::equal_range( idxNameAddress.begin(), idxNameAddress.end(), newId, cmpNameAddress );
    auto p2 = std::equal_range( idxBirthCertificate.begin(), idxBirthCertificate.end(), newId, cmpBirthSert );

    if( p1.first != p1.second or p2.first != p2.second ) {
        People.pop_back();
        return false; // already there
    }
    idxNameAddress.insert( p1.first, newId );
    idxBirthCertificate.insert( p2.first, newId );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried it and it does not work in this case:

CPeople people;
 assert ( person.NewPerson( "Jean", "Kolejni", "abcdef" ) );
 assert ( ! person.NewCompany ( "jEan, "kOlEjNi", "1234" ) );
 
 In the second case it should return false, but it returns true, so it adds a new record although the person with the name and address is same, there is a difference in the capital letters. So it is perhaps sensitive.

Comment: OK, I misunderstand criteria you using to search, answer is updated

Comment: Thank you very much Slava. Finally it works, that is great. I updated my text, if you please have a look at it, you can see it bello the line. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If space is not an issue in your program, you can use `std::map`.

Maintain a map *m1* of . Whenever you call `NewPerson()` update the map m1.

Maintain another map *m2*, for . Whenever you call `NewPerson()` update the map m2.

Every time you add call `NewPerson()`  call the `find()`  of both m1 and m2.

`map.find()`  is logarithmic.